# Problem with three coins, two flips

Tags: probability, proof-verification

**Problem**

A box contains three coins, one of which has two head, another one has two tails, and a third one is normal (one side is head, the other is tail). A coin is extracted from the box at random and the coin is flipped obtaining head.

1) What is the probability of having chosen the coin with two heads?
2) If the coin is tossed one more time, what is the probability of obtaining head again?

**Attempt at a solution**

1) I call $A_1=\{\text{choosing the coin with two heads}\}$,$A_2=\{\text{choosing the normal coin}\}$, $A_3=\{\text{choosing the coin with two tails}\}$ and $B=\{\text{obtaining head when coin is flipped}\}$

I want to calculate $P(A_1|B)$, we have $$P(A_1|B)=P(B|A_1)\dfrac{P(A_1)}{P(B)}$$$$=\dfrac{1.\frac{1}{3}}{\sum_{i=1}^3 P(B|A_i)P(A_i)}$$$$=\dfrac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{3}(1+\frac{1}{2}+0)}$$$$=\dfrac{2}{3}$$

I am lost with part 2) of the exercise and I am not sure if what I've done in 1) is correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to look at it.

In total there are $6$ faces. $3$ of them are head and $3$ of them are tail.

Picking out one of the coins and tossing it to look at the outcome is in fact the same as picking out one of the $6$ faces. This on such a way that the faces have equal probability to be picked out.

If it turns out to be a head, then observe that $2$ of the head-faces are faces of a coin that has heads on both sides, and $1$ of them is the face of a coin that has a tail on the other side.

So the probability that you are dealing with the coin that has heads on both sides is $$\frac23$$

---

If the coin is tossed one more time then the probability that a head is obtained is:$$\frac23\times1+\frac13\times\frac12=\frac56$$

Do you see why? If not then let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have it right so far.

Let us call the coin with two heads $C_H$, the normal coin $C_N$ and the coin with two tails $C_T$.

You select a coin and flip it, getting a head. This rules out the possibility you selected $C_T$. $C_H$ has a 100% chance of getting heads, and $C_N$ has a 50% chance. A heads result implies you are twice as likely to have chosen $C_H$, so yes, $\frac{2}{3}$.

Then, if the coin is tossed again, the probability of heads would be $$\frac{2}{3}×1+\frac{1}{3}×\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your math is correct. If you want to check it think about easier/other approaches to working it out.

Due to the limited number of possibilities you can check this via exhaustion. There are six possible outcomes:

- two headed coin, flip first head
- two headed coin, flip second head
- normal coin, flip head
- normal coin, flip tail
- two tailed coin, flip first tail
- two tailed coin, flip second tail

As we know the outcome was a head it is one of the first three answers. Of these two thirds where a result of picking the two headed coin so your answer of $\frac{2}{3}$ is correct.